# Why isn't my jQuery validation working?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation, asp.net-mvc-5.1

I have this in my Web.config:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />        
</appSettings>
```

My view model:

```
public class CustomerViewModel
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("First Name")]        
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
}
```

My view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(MVC.Customers.Edit(), FormMethod.Post, new { id = "edit-customer" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>        

        ...

    </div>
}
```

And this is how the "form-group" div gets rendered:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="FirstName">First Name</label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <input id="FirstName" class="form-control text-box single-line" name="FirstName" value="" type="text" data-val-required="The First Name field is required." data-val="true">
        <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-for="FirstName"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

And I'm loading the jQuery scripts in this order:

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.4.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
```

The form is shown using an ajax call when a button is clicked. It is also submitted with ajax. This all works fine when I'm not doing any validation. I added validation and I can't get it to trigger before the ajax call. Here's what I'm doing in the click handler that submits the form:

```
var formToSubmit = $('#' + attrData.formIdToSubmit);
if (!formToSubmit.valid()) {
    return false;
}

formData = formToSubmit.serialize();
...
```

I expect `formToSubmit.valid()` to trigger the validation and return `false` when nothing is entered in the FirstName field. In practice it returns true and then validation fails on the server, `ModelState.IsValid` returns `false` as expected. In looking through the jQuery validation docs it looks like it expects a `required` attribute, like this:

```
<input id="FirstName" class="form-control text-box single-line" name="FirstName" value="" type="text" data-val-required="The First Name field is required." data-val="true" required>
```

If I use dev tools to add that and then click the submit button then the call to `formToSubmit.valid()` returns false as expected, however the error message doesn't end up in the `span` created by `@Html.ValidationMessageFor`, it ends up in a newly added label that looks like this:

```
<label for="FirstName" class="error">This field is required.</label>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I ended up fixing it:

```
var formToSubmit = $('#' + attrData.formIdToSubmit);
formToSubmit.removeData("validator")
            .removeData("unobtrusiveValidation");
$.validator.unobtrusive.parse(formToSubmit);
if (!formToSubmit.valid()) {
    return;
}

formData = formToSubmit.serialize();
...
```